# I couldn't connect to Elasticsearch with elasticsearch-php package

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch with docker. I can use Elasticsearch on the browser as localhost:9200.
I need to use Elasticsearch with php so i used elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php package on my project and when i try to connect Elasticsearch i usually get that error : No alive nodes found in your cluster on line 64.

There are a lots of documents about this error but no document didn't work. Maybe i couldn't.
I tried some host like that :

"http://localhost:9200/",
"localhost",
"docker_elastic_1:9200"

But these hosts are couldn't work.

Can you please help me about this error ?

My code :

```
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
];

$response = $client->indices()->create($params);
print_r($response);
```

Error :
[image]